# Why don't stars have emission lines?

Tags: spectroscopy, photon-emission

I understand why stars have absorption lines, but I am not entirely sure why they don't have emission lines. Wouldn't the gas on the surface of the stars be hot enough to at least give off some emission?

Comment: Consider the scale of kT vs an emission line width, much less the entire width of the visible spectrum. 300K is about 23meV, so 3000K is almost a quarter of an eV, so the sun as a blackbody at ~5700K smears emission out over nearly half an eV.

Comment: I found the answer to that one a little confusing, but I think the top comment here answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: @JonCuster emission lines are seen from the Sun and from plasma at temperatures $10^4-10^6$ K. The fractional width of a spectral line is given by $\sim v/c \simeq \sqrt {kT/mc^2}$, not what you suggest.